# Javascript overide object's methods

Tags: javascript

I am developing a JS plugin. All required parameters are wrapped in a   n object. Since there are many methods, the user will miss setting required parameters. In that case, I have built a base option object including all parameters.  When the user's option is passed into plugin function, missing properties should be set to the internal base option.
For example,

```
var option = {
getProp:function(){alert('user prop');} // only one method. No getMsg() 
  };

//Inside the plugin,  two methods
var pluginBaseOption= {
getProp:function(){alert('plugin prop');}
,getMsg : function(){alert('plugin another method');}
};
```

Functions of pluginBaseOption should be overriden by option, but missed functions should be remained. That means, the final option object should be:

```
var finalOption= {
   getProp:function(){alert('user prop');} // user passed method instead of plugin method
    ,getMsg : function(){alert('plugin another method');}
    };
```

I tried using following way,

```
function overide( initObj, baseOption) {
    initObj.prototype = baseOption;
    initObj.prototype.constructor = initObj;
    return initObj;
}
```

But the returned object has none of the overridden methods as it says 'undefined' .

Comment: *"If downvote, please mention the reason."* Comments like that are *never* constructive, and are usually counter-productive as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple extend function like this:

```
function extend(base, obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        base[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return base;
}
```

You can then use it like `extend(pluginBaseOption, option)`.

However, this will only work once, as `pluginBaseOption` itself will be extended. To fix this, we'll need to clone it before extending. Good thing  `extend` itself is able to clone:

```
extend(extend({}, pluginBaseOption), option)
```

Comment: The usual `extend` just accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: True, but there's only so much code i'm willing to write on a question currently at -2.